# How to install drush on a restricted shell access account? Media Temple shared environment

Tags: drush

I'm working with a client that has a media temple server (gs)-gridserver. its a shared environment, but i do have access to the shell.

How would i go about installing drush for an account like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Place drush into your home (~) folder under something like `~/drush/`
2. Create or edit `~/.bash_profile` and add the following: `alias drush='~/drush/drush'`; this creates an alias called 'drush' that will execute drush's main file.
3. If you need to specify which version of PHP to use, add `export DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php`.
4. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload the `.bash_profile` file.

At this point you should be able to use the `drush` command.

In unrelated news: if you can, move your client off MediaTemple. Their database servers are in a physically different location from their web servers, which is an absolute nightmare for applications with a ton of database queries (read: Drupal).